# quartz scheduler run 2 times every day

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

i've a java application that runs on UNIX OS two times at a day every time it generates reports and send the generated files to the configured mail.

the problem is that the reports generated successfully at the first run for the 2 reports but the coming runs it didn't work without mentioning any problems

i've to run 7 jobs the first one will be sent to the first email with the first below corn expression and the 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 jobs will be sent in the second mail with the 2nd below corn expression

what i see might be the problem that i run 6 jobs at the same corn expression if any one have experience with this situation please advice

here is my corn expressions

Query_1_ReportName = Sarie_Outgoing - EFT 103-102-202
Query_1_Time = 0 10 16 ? * *

Query_2_ReportName = Swift_Outgoing - SWF 103
Query_2_Time = 0 0 6 ? * *

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that you second cron trigger is not running?
I have described how we can run multiple crontrigger,hope it may help.
[multiple cron trigger](http://techniqpatch.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-add-multiple-triggers-for-job-in.html)
If it doesnt  help then you need to provide your code so that we can go through the code and identify the problem.